# oracle default value for a column

Tags: oracle

You know how we could use:

```
dateStamp DATE DEFAULT sysdate
```

to assign a default value to a column in table_x. What if I want to assign a default function? Can I do that?

The function will have some values from "table_params" to run some formula including a column named : "base" in table_x.

I could possibly write a cursor to loop through and run an update statement, but I was just curious if this is possible.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write an INSERT trigger for the table that calls the function you want.

Answer (score 3):

From Oracle documentation:

> Restriction on Default Column Values
>   A DEFAULT expression cannot contain references to PL/SQL functions or to other columns, the
>   pseudocolumns CURRVAL, NEXTVAL, LEVEL, PRIOR, and ROWNUM, or date
>   constants that are not fully specified.

Either use a trigger (as was already mentioned) or run an UPDATE statement after your INSERT statement(s) (shouldn't be a problem if you keep your DML in PL/SQL).